# How can I add a woocommerce filter which filters products by sales discount?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have my woocommerce products and I have added some discounts. Is it possible and how to add a filter which gets products if they have discount?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code that you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: I dont have code, I dont know how to do it

Comment: Do you want to display the filtered products on shop page? Are you using any plugin for product filter?

Comment: I would like to display them In admin page. No I am not using any plugin

Comment: See if this thread can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135816/woocommerce-adding-a-custom-filter-to-the-product-admin-area

Answer (score 0):

This is how i am filtering products by available discount, using action

> woocommerce_product_query

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mam_action_woocommerce_product_query'); 
function mam_action_woocommerce_product_query($q) { 

    global $wpdb;
    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;

    $discount_low =  10;
    $discount_high = 20;
    $query = "SELECT p.ID 
FROM ".$prefix."posts p, ".$prefix."postmeta pm1, ".$prefix."postmeta pm2, ".$prefix."postmeta pm3
WHERE 
    p.post_type='product' 
AND p.post_status='publish' 
AND p.ID=pm1.post_id 
AND p.ID=pm2.post_id
AND p.ID=pm3.post_id 
AND ( (pm1.meta_key='_sale_price' AND pm1.meta_value > 0)  ) 
AND pm3.meta_key='_regular_price' AND (  (  (   (CAST(pm3.meta_value AS DECIMAL) - CAST(pm1.meta_value AS DECIMAL)) /  NULLIF(CAST(pm3.meta_value AS DECIMAL),0) )*100) ) >= '$discount_low' 
AND pm3.meta_key='_regular_price' AND (  (  (   (CAST(pm3.meta_value AS DECIMAL) - CAST(pm1.meta_value AS DECIMAL)) /  NULLIF(CAST(pm3.meta_value AS DECIMAL),0) )*100) ) <= '$discount_high' 
GROUP BY p.ID ";
    

        
        
        
    $all_salable_products = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        
    $posts_in_arr = array();

    foreach($all_salable_products as $all_salable_product){
        $posts_in_arr[] = $all_salable_product->ID;
        
    }
    
    $q->set( 'post__in', $posts_in_arr );
    
    if(count($posts_in_arr) == 0)
    wc_add_notice( 'No item matches your criteria', 'notice' );     



return;


    
    
}
```

You can get the complete plugin from [Webostock Marketplace](https://webostock.com/market-item/woocommerce-discount-filter/32140/). Including the widget to be used on shop page.